# Matching identical columns

Tags: r

I would like to get some help on the following problem. I have a dataframe in which I have columns v1, v2, etc. I want to know what are distinct columns in this dataset. The first column is “change_no” and the rest of the columns are serial numbers that are applicable (in this case y) or not applicable (in this case, n) for each of the change numbers.

I want to find the distinct columns of change numbers and after that for each of the serial numbers, I want to map it to the “distinct” change number column that is found. I believe that I am not doing this the most efficient way.

In the example, below, v1 and v4 are identical and v2 and v5 are identical. v3 and v6 do not have duplicate columns. This means that the non duplicate columns are: v1, v2, v3, v6. I now would like to get a mapping like below

v1,v1
v2,v5
v3,v3
v4,v1
v5,v5
v6,v6

```
# get distinct columns and map each column to the distinct column found
library("dplyr")   
library("purrr")   
library("tidyr")   
library("reshape2")   
library("plyr")   
   
   
text1 <- ("   
          change_no,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6   
c1,y,n,y,y,n,n   
          c2,y,n,n,y,n,y   
          c3,n,y,y,n,y,n   
          c4,n,y,y,n,y,y   
          c5,n,n,n,n,n,y   
          c6,y,y,y,y,y,n")   
   
#read the above information and bring that into a dataframe. Now we have the change numbers and the serial numbers that have a y or n for each of the change numbers   
df1 <- read.table(textConnection(text1),  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, strip.white = TRUE, sep=",")   
head(df1)   
   
# do some gather and spread so that we can get the data into rows and we can use constructs like unique etc.   
df2 <- gather(df1, key = "var", value = "val", -c(change_no))   
head(df2)   
   
df3 <- spread(df2, change_no, val)   
head(df3)   
row.names(df3) <- df3$var   
names(df3)   
   
#the data frame df4 now has the change numbers as columns and the serial numbers as row names   
df4 <- select(df3, -c(var))   
head(df4)   
names(df4)   
   
# get the unique rows from the data frame df4. These are the columns that are unique in the dataset df1   
df5 <- unique(df4)   
head(df5)   
nrow(df5)   
names(df5)   
   
#the below is not working. I would have expected that we will get back the rows with row names v1 and v4 but that does not seem to be the case   
match <- match_df(df5[1,],df4 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

A possibly faster option

```
> (s1 <- sapply(df1[-1], toString))
                v1                 v2                 v3                 v4
"y, y, n, n, n, y" "n, n, y, y, n, y" "y, n, y, y, n, y" "y, y, n, n, n, y"
                v5                 v6
"n, n, y, y, n, y" "n, y, n, y, y, n"

> (s2 <- outer(s1, s1, `==`))
      v1    v2    v3    v4    v5    v6
v1  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
v2 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
v3 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
v4  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
v5 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
v6 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

> (s3 <- cbind(1:nrow(s2), max.col(+s2)))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    3    3
[4,]    4    1
[5,]    5    2
[6,]    6    6

> (s4 <- data.frame(`dim<-`(names(df1[-1])[s3], dim(s3))))
  X1 X2
1 v1 v4
2 v2 v2
3 v3 v3
4 v4 v1
5 v5 v2
6 v6 v6
```

---

You can try the code below

```
u <- which(outer(df1[-1], df1[-1], Vectorize(function(x, y) all(x == y))), arr.ind = TRUE)
res <- data.frame(matrix(names(df1[-1])[u[!duplicated(row.names(u)), ]], ncol = 2))
```

which gives

```
> res
  X1 X2
1 v1 v1
2 v4 v1
3 v2 v2
4 v5 v2
5 v3 v3
6 v6 v6
```

---

Let's break the code into steps:

1. Use `outer` to produce a matrix indicating if any pair of two columns is identical

```
> (step1 <- outer(df1[-1], df1[-1], Vectorize(function(x, y) all(x == y))))
      v1    v2    v3    v4    v5    v6
v1  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
v2 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
v3 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
v4  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
v5 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
v6 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

2. `which` with option `arr.ind = TRUE` gives the indices of `TRUE`s in `step1`

```
> (step2 <- which(step1, arr.ind = TRUE))
   row col
v1   1   1
v4   4   1
v2   2   2
v5   5   2
v3   3   3
v1   1   4
v4   4   4
v2   2   5
v5   5   5
v6   6   6
```

3. `!duplicated` filters out the duplicated rows (in terms of row names)

```
> (step3 <- step2[!duplicated(row.names(step2)), ])
   row col
v1   1   1
v4   4   1
v2   2   2
v5   5   2
v3   3   3
v6   6   6
```

4. We assign the columns to `step3` according to the column order (values in `step3`)

```
> (step4 <- names(df1[-1])[step3])
 [1] "v1" "v4" "v2" "v5" "v3" "v6" "v1" "v1" "v2" "v2" "v3" "v6"
```

5. Reshape `step4` in a 2-column matrix

```
> (step5 <- matrix(step4, ncol = 2))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "v1" "v1"
[2,] "v4" "v1"
[3,] "v2" "v2"
[4,] "v5" "v2"
[5,] "v3" "v3"
[6,] "v6" "v6"
```

6. Make `step5` a `data.frame`

```
> (step6 <- data.frame(step5))
  X1 X2
1 v1 v1
2 v4 v1
3 v2 v2
4 v5 v2
5 v3 v3
6 v6 v6
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this - looks really cool and it works!

Comment: For the benefit of myself and others, I was wondering if you can explain the individual steps in the code. Thanks,

Comment: @SatishVadlamani Yes, I added explanations, hope it can help you understand.

Comment: Hello Thomas:
Please see the runtimes below. This is from the actual data that I was working with and it took approximately 3.5 minutes. I need to run this for at least 800 such datasets.   

> start_time <- Sys.time()

> start_time

[1] "2021-05-30 17:20:05 CDT"

> u <- which(outer(df1[-1], df1[-1], Vectorize(function(x, y) all(x == y))), arr.ind = TRUE)

> res <- data.frame(matrix(names(df1[-1])[u[!duplicated(row.names(u)), ]], ncol = 2))

> end_time <- Sys.time()

> end_time

[1] "2021-05-30 17:23:27 CDT"

> ncol(df1)

[1] 1638

> nrow(df1)

[1] 13933

Comment: Thomas, 
Any thoughts and suggestions on how I can make this faster? Or, should this be expected based on the number of rows and columns? The first thought that comes to mind is to switch to constructs available in data.table to do the same thing. Thanks for your thoughts on this.

Comment: @SatishVadlamani I updated my answer so you can check if this could be faster.